# updating in access without having any connection between tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have one table:

**Item Table**

```
name   | Total | Remaining 
chairs | 10    | 0
```

and another table

**Even entry Table**

```
eventname | Chairs 
birthday  | 10
Party     | 20
```

these two tables don't have any relationship(I know it's bad) ...my goal is to sum total of chairs in event table and put them in item field named **Remaining** sorry im new in access.

i.e

```
name   | Total | Remaining 
chairs | 10    | 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Item (Remaining) SELECT SUM(EventEntry.Chairs) FROM EventEntry;
```

Comment: But this will insert new record it will not update the in the same field.. I want this to update on the same field... like update... I try many ways with update but could not do it.... I try with append and it gives me the same result like inserting new record in the table